# Bind value from DataContext to converter parameter

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, infragistics

i have a problem:
I have a datagrid. The DataContext of the grid is set to a collection called 'FinanceTransferEntries' which has a couple of fields. The code segment below shows the first column that is bound the the property 'ID' of the collection (which works fine).

I implemented a converter that colors the background of the cell depending on

1. a static boolen value "IDTransfer" --> works fine too
2. and the value of the current cell of the field.

Here is my problem. I didn't figure out the correct binding statement to access the current value of the 'ID' property.

```
    <igDP:Field Name="ID" Label="ID" Width="Auto"  >
        <igDP:Field.Settings>
            <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="False">
                <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamTextEditor}" >
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DependentBackrgoundConverter}">
                                    <Binding ? />
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type uc:TransferDataUC}}" Path="ViewModel.SelectedFinanceTransferViewModel.FinanceTransferDetailViewModel.IDTransfer" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
            </igDP:FieldSettings>
        </igDP:Field.Settings>
    </igDP:Field>
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't it simply `<Binding Path="ID"/>`?

Comment: I already tried that one. I get the exception `System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ID' property not found on 'object' ''DataRecord' (HashCode=26674058)'. BindingExpression:Path=ID; DataItem='DataRecord' (HashCode=26674058); target element is 'XamTextEditor' (Name=''); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')`

Comment: And what about `<Binding Path="DataItem.ID"/>`?

Comment: That one worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Clemens, the expression

```
<Binding Path="DataItem.ID"/>
```

did it.